# Unable to Process an image transformed in OpenCV via scikit-image

Tags: python, image, opencv, preprocessor, scikit-image

I want to skeletonize an image using the scikit-image module for skeletonization. This image is pre processed by OpenCV library. Given an Image 'Feb_16-0.jpg', I convert it to gray scale, perform the morphological transformation of opening the image, then apply the Gaussian Blur and adaptive thresholding using OpenCV and Python:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize
from skimage.viewer import ImageViewer
img = cv2.imread('Feb_16-0.jpg',0)
kernel = np.ones((1,1),np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(opening,(1,1),0)
ret3,th4 = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

I now want to skeletonize the image using scikit-image skimage.morphology.skeletonize. I have tried writing code for performing erosion and dilation to manually skeletonize the image using OpenCV and Python. But, this proved to be a highly inefficient processing so i decided to switch to the scikit-image library at this point. However, when I pass the numpy array preprocessed by OpenCV to the scikit-image module using the code:

```
skel = skeletonize(th4)
```

and try to view the results of the same, I end up with the error:

```
Image contains values other than 0 and 1
```

I am unable to interpret the cause for the same. Can anyone kindly help me out in resolving this datatype error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see if the below code works.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize
from skimage.viewer import ImageViewer
img = cv2.imread('Feb_16-0.jpg',0)
kernel = np.ones((1,1),np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(opening,(1,1),0)
ret3,th4 = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
th4[th4 == 255] = 1
skel = skeletonize(th4)
viewer = ImageViewer(skel)
viewer.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

The input matrix to `skeletonize()` needs to be binary with either 0/1 or True/False as entries. The output of `cv2.threshold()` is binary, but with values 0/255. To convert the th4 matrix to 0/1 form you can for example do:

`th4[th4 == 255] = 1`

Comment: Hello, I thank you for your kind suggestion. But, I get a similar error on the binarized input th4 instead of img. th4 is the thresholded binarized image.

Comment: Seems like cv2.treshold() returns an array with 255 as white and 0 as black.  You can convert the th4 matrix. I'll edit my post